# How can I test DART's runApp() function

Tags: unit-testing, testing, flutter, dart, flutter-test

I can't reach **100% test** coverage because of DART's `runApp()` function. I tried to create tests for this function, but couldn't. Has anyone created a test for this function?

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
```

My coverage is 96.2% because only one line with the `runApp()` function has no test.

I would like to know how to create a unit test for this function.

[image]

Project source: [full_testing_flutter](https://github.com/chinnonsantos/full_testing_flutter)

Comment: Same question here dude. Did you solved this issue?

Comment: Nop! @NiltonVasques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use comments to tell the coverage calculator to ignore lines:

```
// coverage:ignore-start
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
// coverage:ignore-end
```

I wouldn't recommend letting this strategy permeate the rest of your code, but for this simple one-off, it seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

The strategy I've used is to avoid calling the `runApp` method directly in my code altogether.

You can do this by keeping your code as declarative as possible.

Instead of:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
```

Use something like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'

void main() => AppRunner(
    widget: MyApp(),
    runMethod: runApp,
).run;

class AppRunner{
    AppRunner({
        required this.widget,
        required this.runMethod,
    });

    final Widget widget;
    final Function(Widget) runMethod;

    void run() => runMethod(widget);
}
```

You will also want to test that that your AppRunner's `run` method executes the `runMethod` parameter with the given `widget` parameter to get it to 100%.

Comment: I tried your code, still the same problem, the main() has no test coverage. You cannot still get 100% using this code.